# Python, Eclipse or Windows 10 won't recognize matplotlib

Tags: windows-10, python, eclipse, matplotlib

I'm using Eclipse on Windows 10. I would like to make a function plotter so I started a program as

```
import tkinter

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np
```

Now I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jaakk\eclipse-workspace\Testi\testi.py", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

Why this happens and how to resolve it as I have already run the following command from the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\jaakk>pip3 install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\jaakk\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (3.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in c:\users\jaakk\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.20.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=6.2.0 in c:\users\jaakk\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (8.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.2.1 in c:\users\jaakk\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\jaakk\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\jaakk\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in c:\users\jaakk\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\jaakk\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.15.0)

C:\Users\jaakk>
```

Comment: You have matplotlib  located in a location other than `C:\Users\jaakk\eclipse-workspace\Testi\` is aware of.  Have you looked at your system variables? Are they configured properly?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure how to do it. I'm new in programming and Windows.

Comment: You just have to point Eclipse to correct Python installation

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening?

You may have multiple copies of the Python interpreter installed. Each copy is typically self-contained and does not share resources (including any versions of `pip` or installed packages). Eclipse seems to be pointed at a copy of Python without `matplotlib`.

> I have already run `pip3 install matplotlib` from the command prompt.

Each copy of Python will often come with its own (separate) copy of `pip` to manage (separate) packages for a given installation. So it is
possible to have:

- `C:\Folder1\Python\python.exe`
- `C:\Folder1\Python\Scripts\pip.exe`
- `C:\Folder1\Python\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib`

and

- `C:\Folder2\Python\python.exe`
- `C:\Folder2\Python\Scripts\pip.exe`
- `C:\Folder2\Python\Lib\site-packages\no matplotlib here`

Note that e.g. `pip3` can only be used from the command line with one path.

So if `pip3` references `C:\Folder1\Python\Scripts\pip3.exe`, then `matplotlib` would be installed in `C:\Folder1\Python\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib`. However, if Eclipse is using `C:\Folder2\Python\python.exe` to run Python programs, it will look in `C:\Folder2\Python\Lib\site-packages\no matplotlib here` and thus be unable to find `matplotlib`.

> How do I resolve this?

Ensure that Eclipse is pointing to the Python interpreter with `matplotlib` installed.

I would suggest looking under (I believe) *Window* → *Preferences* → *PyDev* → *Interpreter* to find the path that Eclipse is using for `python.exe` and compare that to the path for `pip3` from `where pip3` (run from the command line).

Then you could either:

- Change the interpreter path in Eclipse to match the same base folder as `pip3` (so e.g. `C:\Folder2\Python\python.exe` might become `C:\Folder1\Python\python.exe`).

or

- Edit your environment variables so that e.g. `pip3` is associated with the same base folder as the `python.exe` used by Eclipse (so e.g. `C:\Folder1\Python\Scripts\pip3.exe` might become `C:\Folder2\Python\Scripts\pip3.exe`). Note that you would need to rerun `pip3 install matplotlib` in this case.